# Interpreting data from ASTER GDEM

Tags: matlab, graphics

So I've downloaded ASTER GDEM data for a particular island and I'd like to recreate an image like this:
[image: Image from ASTER GDEM]

I thought I would simply have to use the values in the given .tif file, like I did in this Matlab code

```
elevationImage = imread('Elevation.tif');
elevation = elevationImage(:,:,1);
h = pcolor(elevation);
colorbar();
caxis([0, 15]);
set(h, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
set(gca, 'YDir','reverse')
```

But that resulted in this image

[image: My Image]

The most obvious issue is the height of the ocean being non-zero, and large streaks across the image. I thought that maybe you have to manually find where the ocean is and set the height of that to zero, but the streaks go across the island at some points so that wouldn't be a complete solution. What do I need to do to recreate an image like the first one from the data I have?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was quite a simple mistake. The downloaded data came with two files, one ending with DEM and one ending with NUM. The DEM file has the elevation data, and the NUM file has quality assurance data, I was accidently drawing the NUM file instead of the DEM file.